# Image is not displaying in cfdocument pdf for coldfusion 10

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfdocument

I am using ColdFusion 10 Enterprise edition, and am unable to display images when using `CFDOCUMENT` to generate a PDF. Below is the piece of code I am using:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="report">
   <table align='center'>
    <cfoutput query="VARIABLES.result">
            <tr>
              <td>
                 <div class='addInfoDetails'>#SHOWINFO#</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
       </cfoutput>  
   </table>
</cfsavecontent>
```

In the above code, the `VARIABLES.result` query is coming from database and `SHOWINFO` is a variable having the content of image and text. For example:

```
 SHOWINFO  = 
 "<p> Hi This is the test information
     <img alt="image" src="../TestBank/test/info/5KQ.jpg"/>
 </p>"
```

Here if dump the `SHOWINFO`  variable inside the `CFSAVECONTENT`, the image displays correctly. But when I convert this into PDF, using CFDOCUMENT, the image is not displaying.

Below is the code block I am using to generate the pdf:

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" saveasname="TestPDF">
  <cfoutput>#report#</cfoutput>
</cfdocument>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the attribute `"localUrl = yes"` in CFDOCUMENT tag.

Now it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm saving the created pdf and find `localUrl="yes"` (or `=true`) fails. Turns out CF generating pdfs for https urls is painfully finicky.

```
<img src="file:\\\#replace(getCurrentTemplatePath(),"my.cfm")#images\my.png">
```

Worked for me, in case anyone is scraping the bottom of the barrel for ideas. getCurrentTemplatePath() gets the filename as well as the path, so I had to remove it (hence the replace(...,"my.cfm"). I also tried expandPath(".") and that failed as well.

Didn't try Dave Anderson's intriguing suggestion to grab the image [Coldfusion CFDOCUMENT creates a red X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637542/coldfusion-cfdocument-creates-a-red-x)

Comment: nice - this fixed it